# bypassing or setting cache to zero in Internet Explorer 7?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7

I've been in Internet Options to delete the cache, used the delete cache option in Microsofts Developer Tools, turned off the server cache beforehand of course, added

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
```

to my html5 page and reloaded with the page Ctrl-F5.

Yet the only thing that reliably helps IE7 to get that I have updated my css-files is to change the name of it. That's a nuisance of course.

Is there some way to set the cache to zero in Internet Explorer or reliably bypass it? Even better would be some way to edit css in realtime like in Firefox, but all of what supported that seem to be gone now.

Comment: Does CTRL+SHIFT+R reload the page without the cache? It works in most browsers - can't test it as I don't have ie 7

Comment: Well @starbeamrainbowlabs, thanks for the response. It seems alt-D + Reload button does the trick more often than not, but I'm getting this problem now also in other browsers. Perhaps I  haven't really turned the server cache off completely. I used this code on the Apache server, but only on the server root.`<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
FileETag None
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</filesMatch>`